# Capacitor Discharge Test

Tags: filter, emc

I have a device with 3 different power supplies in one of my product. Now the complete device is powered using an IEC filter connector with following circuit digram.[image: Schematic]

I have two questions:

1. What is the role of resistor here?
2. What will be the effect of changing value of Cy here (if I increase or decrease it?) ?

Answer (score 2):

The resistor is probably to bleed off any charge within a reasonable time.  This prevents someone from getting zapped by unplugging the cord, then touching the plug pins.

Cy filter out some of the high frequency harmonics on the power line, and reduce the maximum voltage of spikes.  Since they are on the load side, they are to present a bit cleaner power to the load.  Depending on the impedance presented by the load, they can also help filter noise produced by the load from getting onto the power line.

Note that the Cy capacitors filter single ended signals, while Cx filters differential mode noise produced by the device.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. can you please confirm that in a connector that does not have this resistor the possibility of voltage remaining in the connector even after its plugged off remains ?

Comment: @AkankshaDixit - If the internal device load is always attached and then the cord is pulled out the the capacitors will discharge via the load. On the other hand if the device has a power switch that is wired into the load side of the filter then there is a possibility of charge remaining on the filters capacitors when the cord is pulled out when the power switch was already open.